# Original back button in iOS navigation bar shows briefly after replacing it with a custom one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Before I begin, I just want to give some background info. I have implemented a custom back button before, in an iOS app of mine. Back then, I got it working in minutes, so it was a really nice experience.

This this time, however, I faced strange problems. First, the custom back button did not show at all. Then, I got it to overlap the original back button. I could, however, never remove the original back button.

I was at a loss until I found the answer here: http://smartercoder.com/2010/10/18/what-to-do-it-self-navigationitem-hidesbackbutton-true-doesnt-work. The solution was to set a dummy left button and remove it, before telling the navigation item to hide the back button and add the custom button.

However, although the custom button now replaces the original one, the result is not as nice as in my first app. I still see the original back button briefly, during the push transition. Clearly, it would be better if it did not to show up at all.

This is the code that I run in **viewDidLoad**:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem barButtonItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar-button-back"] andAction:@selector(triggerBackNavigation:) withTarget:self];
```

If anyone knows how to entirely remove the original back button during the push transitions (both forward and backwards) as well, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing your code now. It all seems to be working well. But I would definitely call this first:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

After you call this then create your new leftBarButtonItem. The full code that I used is below:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi"
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(triggerBackNavigation:)];
```

I know you're using an image but I just used a button with text to see if it works properly.

Comment: i don't understand what's need of hiding backButton we easily set custom back-button as a left button then default back button automatic overlap @dana what need of *self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;* can you explain

Comment: Because you cannot customize the original back bar item with an image. You can only set the text of the back bar item. If you want to set an image for the back bar item you would need to hide it and use the leftBarButtonItem property to a custom button.

Comment: i dont think so its necessory to hide default back button check my answer and i atteched also demo there i am not hiding back button just set leftBarbutton with image.

Comment: Thank you for replying, dana. If I call hidesBackButton before the two lines of faux left button set/reset, the back button is not hidden. I must, however, add it before setting the real leftBarButton. However, although the code I posted works, I still see the original back button during the push animation. In my other app, I do not need to use the faux left button approach at all, and the original back button does not show up at all, not even during the push animation. I use the exact same code in both apps (except the faux left btn code) so it is rather confusing.

Comment: @DanielSaidi Try calling this right after instantiating the modal view controller: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @dana0550 I never made this work. The back button is working as it should when pushing a view on the navigation stack. When pressing the back button, however, the original back button briefly shows during the back animation.